# Failure to build arch package - aborting

Tags: archlinux

I'm trying to build a package for ArchLinux with the following command:

`extra-x86_64-build -cr archbuild`

It fails with the following error:

```py
Dropping capabilities failed: Operation not permitted
Child died too early.
==> ERROR: Aborting...
```

I have no idea why is it failing.

Update: Running as root or a normal user makes no difference, both return the same error.

Comment: Are you running this as root?

Comment: @NickHale running as a normal user, not a root.

Comment: I think last time I did this, I had to use `sudo`, I'm just trying to confirm that now

Comment: Running as root also gives the same error.